# google translate API and mathjax latex translation issue

Tags: google-translate, mathjax, google-translation-api

hello here is my code you may understand the whole issue from this

```
    <?php

require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');
use \Statickidz\GoogleTranslate;

$source = 'en';
$target = 'hi';
$text = "<p>This is a test equation <span translate='no' class='math-tex notranslate'> test me \(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>to check something<span class='math-tex notranslate'>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>";

$trans = new GoogleTranslate();
$result = $trans->translate($source, $target, $text);

echo $result;
?>
<html>
<p>
  <br/>
=============== THIS IS THE ORIGINAL TEXT =================
<br/><br/>
  This is a test equation <span class='math-tex notranslate'>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>to check something<span class='math-tex notranslate'>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>


</html>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=default'></script>
```

> when i translate the text from english hindi all works good but my
>   math equation gets issue. it dosent works like it should. i have added
>   the live version here http://ynapsweb.site/pro/test/ please do let me
>   know where i am doing wrong.

i am also looking to solve this if i get the answer i will post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with the HTML that prevent rendering

- extra space in delimiter: `\ (` instead of `\(`
- pre and code elements: by default, MathJax ignores these elements, cf.  skipTags in http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/tex2jax.html

There's also extra space inside the span tag declarations (< span> etc) which you probably want to fix -- but those do not influence MathJax.

With those fixed, everything renders fine.

```html
<p> यह एक परीक्षण समीकरण है <span Translate = 'no' class = 'notranslate'> परीक्षण me \ (x = {-b \ pm \ sqrt {b ^ 2-4ac} \ over 2a} \) </ span > कुछ जाँचने के लिए <span class = 'notranslate'> \ _ (x = {-b \ pm \ sqrt {b ^ 2-4ac} \ over 2a} \) </ span> </ p> <p> परीक्षण </ p> <p> परीक्षण </ p> <p> परीक्षण </ p><html>
<p>
  <br/>
=============== THIS IS THE ORIGINAL TEXT =================
<br/><br/>
  This is a test equation <span class='notranslate'>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>to check something<span class='notranslate'>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>


  <br/>
=============== THIS IS THE ORIGINAL TEXT in codeing =================
<br/><br/>

This is a test equation <span class='notranslate'>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>to check something <span class='notranslate'>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=default'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i really appreciate your help. but the points you mentioned is i did it intentionally to show the real code sorry for that. what i wanted to show you is the first translation is not working . 

what i want to fix is the first line which is in hindi ..

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood your post.